# The best beam size to construct a small bridge over a stream on my property

Tags: beam, support

I have a stream that divides my camping land. I need to "bridge" that stream to get access to the other side. The bridge must be capable of carrying **at least 2500 lbs** to enable me to get my small Bobcat over there, when needed, to do earth moving work.

Looking at the size of the stream, I estimate I would use 12' long **2 x ___ beams** on 16" centers to a width of 80" for about a 6.5' wide bridge. Then use 2 x 4's laying flat from one side to the other with 1" of space between them.

The beams would be supported on each side 12" in from the end with 6 x 6 pressure treated beams sitting on the ground. So, basically, the final span of the beams would be around 10'.

I'd like to be safe but still use the minimal size beam possible just to make things easier for me doing the work, alone. If I can use 2 x 6's for the beams that will also make it easier to raise the ground at each end and not have to also build a wooden ramp on each side.

Can someone help me to determine what size beams I will need to use?

Comment: Get an engineer to spec this correctly. If you get an answer from the internet and it fails then your insurance will pay out zero..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be properly calculated by an engineer.

Comment: Have you thought about using culverts instead of wood.

Comment: @matt. do you think it is “home improvement” or an access issue?

Comment: @SolarMike   Most people who are in this situation will not bother insurance about it.  They will get get their or a neighbours tractor to pull them out and build better next time.  I imagine this is for a small stream/ditch, maybe three or four feet deep.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hire an engineer. The devil is in the details for work like this. You need formal drawings. I'll fill in your blank and check your design, though, so you can approximate a cost.

**Joists**

For a 10 ft span carrying 1250# (half the total weight), the bending demand is

(1250#)(10ft)(12in/ft)/4 = 37500 #-in.

For a 40 psf live load instead and joists on 16 inch centers, the demand would instead be

(40psf)(16in)(1ft/12in)(10ft)²(12in/ft)/8 = 8000 #-in.

That's not concurrent with the Bobcat, so the Bobcat load is the one to check.

For a Structural Select grade 2×12 of Spruce-Pine-Fir (Douglas Fir, Southern Pine, and Hemlock-Fir are all stronger), the bending moment capacity is

(1440psi)(1/6)(1.5in)(11.5in)²/1.15 = 41400 #-in,

where I've divided by the "repetitive use factor" of 1.15 to convert the design value from the AWC's 2021 *Design Values for Joists and Rafters*. This strength should be adequate. While the dead load could push the demand higher than this value, I've neglected a load duration factor that should compensate for the dead load. Two #2 grade 2×12s provide greater strength than a single Structural Select grade 2×12, so that would be an okay substitution.

With a span length to depth ratio of 10, I don't think that checking deflection is worth the trouble. I believe that Structural Select grade SPF 2×12s will be adequate for your bridge. If you've got a better species of lumber available locally (it varies by region), then 2×10s could potentially work.

**Deck**

For 16 inch deck spans, the bending moment demand is

(1250#)(16in)/4 = 5000 #-in.

For #2 grade Southern Pine 2×4s, the bending capacity is

(1265psi)(1/6)(3.5in)(1.5in)²(1.1)/1.15 = 1590 #-in,

where I've multiplied by the NDS's "flat use factor" and again divided by the "repetitive use factor." This is totally inadequate. The solution (rather than a stronger deck) should be some sort of rail system that forces your Bobcat to track directly on top of joists. Or maybe a couple 2×8s laying flat on top of joists to delineate a stronger path, where signage could indicate 2 capacities—one for the 2×8s and one for the deck. Under this design, only two of the joists would be Structural Select, while #2 grade would be adequate for the others.

The bending moment demand for a 40 psf live load is

(40psf)(3.5in+1in)(1ft/12in)[(16in)(1ft/12in)]²(12in/ft)/8 = 40 #-in.

The 2×4 deck, then, is probably overdoing it for 16 inch spans. 5/4 inch deck boards are typical for a deck with 16 inch spans, so 5/4 inch material should work (assuming that the Bobcat load never shows up in deck bending). To minimize cost, I suspect that 24 inch joist spacing and pressure treated plywood with a */24 span rating is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation, on my previous property I dropped in a 1800 diameter concrete pipe (culvert) and then poured concrete around it.

1. Its strong
2. With a low "bridge" the water can flow over it without destroying it for when it really rains.

In my case this was just a bit wider than the width of the stream.  So it was a tight fit.  In your case, you could use multiple pipes to span the width.

Comment: Presumably that's 1800mm/180cm/1.8m/70.8inches/5.9feet?